# "Ladies and gentlemen"

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, vocabulary

Is there a Latin phrase that could be used like "ladies and gentlemen" when addressing a large audience but without commenting the circumstances or identities of the people involved?
In special cases I can use more specific expressions (*amicae amicique* or *cari collegae*), but my vocabulary does not contain a good expression that I could use in almost any situation.
Attested classical greetings are preferred but not required.

Comment: It's a shame that "Quirites" won't really do. :)

Comment: @JoelDerfner, *Quirites* does "comment the circumstances" a bit too much. :o) But there are situations for that one as well...

Comment: For what it's worth, I have always used either _dominae dominique_ or _feminae virique_, though I can't back that up with any sources. It's just what I use.

Comment: @SamK, I quite like *dominae dominique*. You can write that as an answer. I didn't demand authentic expressions, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, I have two phrases that I use during this situation.

1. *Dominae dominique*

   - I prefer this one because it retains the English subtext. When saying "ladies and gentlemen," we are literally calling the audience the mistresses and masters of their households, which is a connotation that this translation also has. (It also sounds cool.)
2. *Feminae virique*

   - This one literally means "women and men," and could also be used, maybe for a more informal setting, but even then (in English at least) we still use "ladies and gentlemen."

---

Please note that these are my personal creations, and not (to my knowledge) idiomatic Latin.